# Text fields - keyboard, inputType

Tags: android-softkeyboard, android-virtual-device, android-inputtype

I use Android Studio and a AVD emulator.

When I run apps with the EditText widget on a AVD emulator, the alphanumeric keyboard is not displayed.

The parameter "Has hardware keyboard" is turned off on my AVD config, yet the virtual keyboard is not displayed.

I tried playing with the inputType property but without success.
what do I need to add/change in order to get the virtual keyboard on screen?

```
<EditText
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/topTextInput"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
android:width="300dp"
android:inputType="textAutoComplete|text"/>
```

Comment: I've never had to add any extra information into layout information. Perhaps your AVD is just very unresponsive?
(I simply have the property "Hardware keyboard present" not checked)
- I would be tempted to create a new AVD phone, perhaps with a different API. Who knows.

Comment: Thank you @GaryRead . I was looking at the wrong configuration parameter!

Wrong one: AVD Manager | AVD | Edit this AVD | Change | select my AVD | Edit Device | Has hardware keyboard.




Correct one: AVD Manager | AVD | Edit this AVD | Show advanced settings | Enable keyboard input